# Docker: how to get ownership of $HOME?

Tags: r, docker, permissions, chown

I have a function Docker image which runs a specific analysis pipeline: the pipeline runs correctly, I get my results, the container exits etc. However, I am getting warnings/errors that a certain java program used by my pipeline fails to make 2 folders.

A few important details:

- I provide inputs to the pipeline via the mount and the results are output there. When using the --user option, all seems to work: the output files have the same permissions as the inputs (i.e they are owned by me, $USER, not root).
- I am using the --user option to ensure I don't run the container as root and to make sure my output files have the correct permissions. More specifically, I use the command:

  ```
  docker run --rm --mount type=bind,source=$(pwd),target=/pipeline/project --user "$(id -u):$(id -g)" pipelineimage:vx.x.x
  ```
- To be clear, the pipeline code is included inside the image. It is in /pipeline. The results are output in /pipeline/project (where project is mounted to my host). The program attempts to make 2 folders: 1 in /pipeline/project and 1 in $HOME. Strangely, my pipeline does successfully make other folders (such as pipeline/project/results) during the analysis and this works.

**My question is:** Is this a permissions issue?
While I don't need the contents of these folders, I am confused why the making of these 2 folders is failing. Why can I create a /pipeline/project/results) but not the other 2 folders? Annoyingly, I cannot prevent this java program from making these folders - it is an automatic behavior I can't change.

**UPDATE: I have established this is a permissions issue**. In short:

- $HOME is owned by root - not the $USER I specified with docker run
- /pipeline (which I used as WORKDIR in my Dockerfile) is also owned by root
- Only the mounted project folder is owned by me, $USER

So the question: what is the best way to handle this? I have seen posts about --chown but should I really be using that to own the $HOME or / and my WORKDIR? Seems quite drastic. I should also point out this image will be used by colleagues, not just me, so specifying a user inside the Dockerfile (useradd) is not really ideal.

Thanks

Comment: Do you actually need Docker here, especially if the thing you're running is a Java application?  A single `java -jar ...` command, that will use the host filesystem and host users, seems simpler than this Docker setup.

Comment: This pipeline uses java but also R and various other linux depencies so I really want to containerize it so I can share it easily